# My HTML Button With Active Link Won't Show Image in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css

So I am not in coding as a professional, this was something I learned over brief research for marketing purposes. I have created a HTML button for applicants to apply to our company through Craigslist. The only thing is that while the active link works, the image of the button appears to be broken while in Google Chrome. It appears in Firefox and other browsers. It used to show in Chrome but suddenly stopped showing. Please help. See code sample and two images of same HTML button and post below:

```
<a href="http://www.driver-reach.com/l/zkhdr?ls=6662" style="cursor:pointer;" >
 <img src="http://hireflo.com/img_pub/apply_now.png" border="0" />
```

[Image of broken button in Google Chrome on Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFDgD.png)

[Image of button on Safari browser on iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC5xU.png)

Answer (score 1):

If your run your code you will an SSL error in the JS console, named `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`.

```html
  <a href="http://www.driver-reach.com/l/zkhdr?ls=6662" style="cursor:pointer;" >
     <img src="http://hireflo.com/img_pub/apply_now.png" border="0" />
    </a>
```

I uploaded your image to another service with SSL and works OK:

```html
<a href="http://www.driver-reach.com/l/zkhdr?ls=6662" style="cursor:pointer;" >
 <img src="https://i.ibb.co/BVjDYsN/apply-now.png" border="0" />
</a>
```

Since Chrome is blocking no-SSL URL, you should consider [get a SSL certificate](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/7630973?hl=en) for your site. Hope you find this useful :)

Comment: This is very helpful, I will explore more into the SSL option. Thank you for taking the time to answer! Much obliged.